# DateTime parsing - unexpected result

Tags: c#

I have datetime string

```
dateStr = "2017-03-21T23:00:00.000Z";
```

then I am calling

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
```

and unexpectedly my date equals

```
22.03.2017 00:00:00
```

I expected it to be 21.03.2017
What's going on here?

Comment: UTC date being converted to your local timezone.

Comment: @ColinMackay is it possible to ignore my local timezone? Is there any cleaner solution than getting substring "2017-03-21" and then parsing this?

Comment: Do you need time also after parsing or only date part?

Comment: @chindiralasampathkumar only date part

Comment: `var date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateStr, null).DateTime;`

Comment: @kriss See my answer below for an expanded explanation.

Comment: Well, clearly 23:00:00 on the 21st of march 2017 UTC is midnight 22nd of march 2017 in your local timezone. Which date do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse()` is locale specific and will take into account your local time zone when parsing dates.

If you are in CET (Central European Time) during the winter your offset is one hour ahead of UTC. The date given is marked with a `Z` indicating it is in UTC, so `DateTime.Parse()` will adjust that to your local timezone.

There is an [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to change that behaviour if you want, by specifying a specific [DateTimeStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) enum. `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` is what you are looking for as that should keep the DateTime as UTC.

And if you only want the date part afterwards, you can just call `.Date` on the `DateTime` object you got back from `Parse()`

So, something like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal).Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

if the date format does not change then you can use the below code to get date part from date string. But it is a bit risky due to its strict dependency on the input format.

```
        string dateStr = "2017-03-21T23:00:00.000Z";
        int year = Int32.Parse(dateStr.Substring(0, 4));
        int month = Int32.Parse(dateStr.Substring(5, 2));
        int day = Int32.Parse(dateStr.Substring(8, 2));
        var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the format of type 'DateTime' variable is 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'.
If you run this code:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

You'll see '24/03/2017 12:54:47'
If you have 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, add .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), then:

```
string dateStr = "2017-03-21T23:00:00.000Z";
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Result:'24-03-2017'